# Procedure in SQL Server query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

```
INSERT INTO #tempbe_budget 
SELECT budgetno, 
       Isnull(finyear, '')                            AS Finyear, 
       Isnull(bud.deptid, 0)                          AS Deptid, 
       Isnull(bud.costcode, '')                       AS Costcode, 
       Isnull(secname, '')                            AS Secname, 
       Isnull(oldno, '')                              AS OldNo, 
       Isnull(newno, '')                              AS Newno, 
       Isnull(iaeacode, '')                           AS IAEA, 
       Isnull(bud.description, '')                    AS Description, 
       Isnull(supplier, 0)                            AS Supplier, 
       Isnull(bud.category, '')                       AS Category, 
       Isnull(subcategory, '')                        AS SubCategory, 
       Isnull(status, '')                             AS Status, 
       Isnull(bud.phyprg, 0)                          AS Phyprogress, 
       Isnull(phytarget, 0)                           AS PhyTarget, 
       Isnull(emp.empname, '')                        AS Engrname, 
       Isnull(bud.empid, 0)                           AS Empid, 
       Isnull(refno, '')                              AS RefNo, 
       Isnull(CONVERT(DATETIME, issueddate, 103), '') AS Issueddate, 
       Isnull(cost, 0)                                AS Cost, 
       Isnull(CONVERT(DATETIME, deldate, 103), '')    AS Deldate, 
       Isnull(budgettype, '')                         AS BudgetType, 
       Isnull(reapr, 0)                               AS Reapr, 
       Isnull(remay, 0)                               AS Remay, 
       Isnull(rejun, 0)                               AS Rejun, 
       Isnull(rejul, 0)                               AS Rejul, 
       Isnull(reaug, 0)                               AS Reaug, 
       Isnull(resep, 0)                               AS Resep, 
       Isnull(reoct, 0)                               AS Reoct, 
       Isnull(renov, 0)                               AS Renov, 
       Isnull(redec, 0)                               AS Redec, 
       Isnull(rejan, 0)                               AS Rejan, 
       Isnull(refeb, 0)                               AS Refeb, 
       Isnull(remar, 0)                               AS Remar, 
       Isnull(recurfy, 0)                             AS Recurfy, 
       Isnull(committedcost, 0)                       AS Committedcost, 
       Isnull(orgdept, '')                            AS OrgDept, 
       Isnull(bud.remarks, '')                        AS Remarks, 
       Isnull(dept.deptname, '')                      AS Department, 
       bepobcno, 
       bepopono, 
       bepopodate, 
       bepopaiduptomarch04, 
       bepocurfinyrexp, 
       bepopovalue, 
       bewobcno, 
       bewowono, 
       bewowodate, 
       bewopaiduptomarch04, 
       bewocurfinyrexp, 
       bewowovalue, 
       bewofinalrevisionvalue, 
       bewowoenddate, 
       tpo.beposname, 
       two.bewosname, 
       Isnull(two.bewoactexp0102, 0)                  BEWOActExp0102, 
       Isnull(two.bewoactexp0203, 0)                  BEWOActExp0203, 
       Isnull(two.bewoactexp0304, 0)                  BEWOActExp0304, 
       Isnull(two.bewoactexp0405, 0)                  BEWOActExp0405, 
       Isnull(two.bewoactexp0506, 0)                  BEWOActExp0506, 
       Isnull(two.bewoactexp0607, 0)                  BEWOActExp0607, 
       Isnull(two.bewoactexp0708, 0)                  BEWOActExp0708, 
       Isnull(two.bewoactexp0809, 0)                  BEWOActExp0809, 
       Isnull(two.bewoactexp0910, 0)                  BEWOActExp0910, 
       Isnull(two.bewoactexp1011, 0)                  BEWOActExp1011, 
       Isnull(two.bewoactexp1112, 0)                  BEWOActExp1112, 
       Isnull(two.bewoactexp1213, 0)                  BEWOActExp1213, 
       Isnull(two.bewoactexp1314, 0)                  BEWOActExp1314, 
       Isnull(two.bewoactexp1415, 0)                  BEWOActExp1415 
   FROM   
       budget bud 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN 
       womaster wo ON wo.bcno1516 = bud.newno 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN 
       department dept ON dept.deptid = bud.deptid 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN 
       #tempbewo two ON two.bewobcno = bud.newno 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN 
       #tempbepo tpo ON tpo .bepobcno = bud.newno 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN 
       employee emp ON emp.empid = bud.empid 
   WHERE  
       budgettype = 'BE' 
       AND finyear = '2016-17' 
   ORDER BY 
       dept.dept_group;
```

Running this query results in an error:

> Msg 468, Level 16, State 9, Line 3
>   Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Latin1_General_CI_AI" in the equal to operation.
>
> Msg 213, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

Comment: sql server 2014 not working

Comment: Um, yes it is. SQL Server 2014 is working fine. It's being used every day by thousands (if not millions) of people every single day, including those at my office.

Comment: Make sure the `columns` used in join condition has same collation. example `wo.bcno1516 = bud.newno` here both `wo.bcno1516` and `bud.newno` should have similar collation. If `wo.bcno1516` is of `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` collation and `bud.newno` is of `Latin1_General_CI_AI` then you will get this error.

Comment: Second error is quite self explanatory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You better specify all columns after your table `#tempbe_budget` like following:

   INSERT INTO #tempbe_budget(
   budgetno,
   Finyear,
   Deptid,
   .....
   )
2. Add collation adjustment to your JOINS:

   FROM budget bud 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN womaster wo 
       ON wo.bcno1516 COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS = bud.newno COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
   LEFT OUTER JOIN department dept 
       ON dept.deptid COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS = bud.deptid COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
   LEFT OUTER JOIN #tempbewo two 
       ON two.bewobcno COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS = bud.newno COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
   LEFT OUTER JOIN #tempbepo tpo 
       ON tpo .bepobcno COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS = bud.newno COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
   LEFT OUTER JOIN employee emp 
       ON emp.empid COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS = bud.empid COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

I'm not sure which one cause an error, you can experiment with that, but I'd guess collation of your database is different from Server collation and affects joins only to Temp tables.

3. By your column names I see that they can be type INT and not CHAR/VARCHAR. Strongly suggest have appropriate data type.